# Titanium: iPhone app to android problems

Tags: android, performance, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have created an iPhone app which works perfectly smooth on my simulator. Now I try to deploy it on an android device (i've tried it on the simulator and also on an android device) and my app runs very slow. It laggs like hell when you even just scroll down, and it takes like 5 seconds to load a page.

Is there anything that could cause this slow behavior?

I'm using Titanium SDK 1.6.2, and when running on the emulator I'm using Android 2.3. - API level 10.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried deploying your app to an iPhone device? How does it perform?  Is your Android device perhaps already doing too much?

Comment: you are going to have to provide more information... what does your app do would be a good place to start....

Comment: Sorry, My app is a congress app. So it gives all possible speakers in a tableview, or all the sessions in a tableview. You can also see a floor plan which is an image overlapped with views. When I open the app and click on the speakers tab, it already takes 3 seconds, not to say how long it takes to load the sessions tab (10 seconds or so). And the scrolling is also very slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Titanium Mobile SDk v1.8 from the continuous build seems to speed up the the tableviews.

You can download it from http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html .

Also, I hooked-up my Android device to my Mac and have Titanium Studio install my app there. Much faster than doing so to the Android emulator.

Moreover, some features like playing movies from remote sources don't work on the emulator, but work on the Android device.

Answer (score 1):

The Titanium Appcelerator TableViews are just dead slow on android. Go look through their Q&A section and you'll find ou're not the only one having this issue. Your best bet is to remove as much complexity as you can or possibly pre-render every row as an image and put it in a scroll view.